# How can i get cities, their countries and their timezones(i.e GMT+0.0) in flutter for time app?

Tags: flutter, datetime, time, pub.dev

How can i get cities, their countries and their timezones(i.e GMT+0.0) in flutter for time app.

I am trying to clone my local time app, which requires City name, country name and its GMT time. I dont know from where i can get this all 3 info. So far i got the timezone cities and their subcontinests via flutter_native_timezone-2.0.0{https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone/example}. Have a look at these screenshots to see what i want [image: Required thing] & what i am getting [image: Right Now].

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Timezone package](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) has the official `tzdata` mapping for current and expected timezones, plus historical information back to the unix epoch. (It is by necessity updated 3-4 times a year, because politicians keep wanting to mess with timezones.) However, this is only a mapping of the zones to times.  You still need geo information to map a location to a zone.